# Django Rest Framework Serializer add elements to Meta.fields

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a custom serializer class that I created copying the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37445248/how-to-dynamically-change-depth-in-django-rest-framework-nested-serializers), but in this example the `fields` parameter replaces original `Meta.fields` attribute, and what I want is to **add** new elements to `Meta.fields`. Is there any way this can be done?

This is my serializer:

```
class DynamicModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        fields = kwargs.pop('fields', None)
        add_fields = kwargs.pop('add_fields', None)
        exclude = kwargs.pop('exclude', None)
        nest = kwargs.pop('nest', None)

        if nest is not None:
            self.Meta.depth = nest

        super(DynamicModelSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if fields is not None:
            allowed = set(fields)
            existing = set(self.fields.keys())
            for field_name in existing - allowed:
                self.fields.pop(field_name)

        if exclude is not None:
            for field_name in exclude:
                self.fields.pop(field_name)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can do that, change your DynamicModelSerializer as below:

```
class DynamicModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        fields = kwargs.pop('fields', None)
        add_fields = kwargs.pop('add_fields', None)
        exclude = kwargs.pop('exclude', None)
        nest = kwargs.pop('nest', None)

        if nest is not None:
            self.Meta.depth = nest

        super(DynamicModelSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if fields is not None:
            allowed = set(fields)
            existing = set(self.fields.keys())
            for field_name in existing - allowed:
                self.fields.pop(field_name)

        if add_fields is not None:
            for field_name, field_class in add_fields.items():
                ### first pop the old field class from the fields if it's there
                if field_name in self.fields:
                    self.fields.pop(field_name)
                ### now add the field to the fields
                self.fields[field_name] = field_class


        if exclude is not None:
            for field_name in exclude:
                self.fields.pop(field_name)
```

Usage:

```
class ExampleSerializer(DynamicModelSerializer):
    test1 = serializers.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = Example
        fields = ('test1', 'test2', 'test3')


ser = ExampleSerializer(fields=('test1', 'test3'), add_fields={'addField1': serializers.CharField()})
```

Comment: Great!! Thanks a lot